# Array Bowling Score

Tags: java, arrays

When I run my code it outputs additional information.

However, I emailed my professor and he said "looks like your loop is extracting more data from the file, your printArray method is missing the parameter that tells the method how many valid values are in the array. Instead it should be " `printArray(blue_members, blue_scores, n);` " where n is the number of valid elements in the array"

After I showed him my some what fix he replied with "NO!!!! you are failing to understand the concept. the max capacity of the arrays should be 10 the printArray method should take as a parameter the valid elements in each array, the teamb and the teamw integer objects keep track of hoe many valid elements are in the arrays" Now I am a visual person and I do not understand what he's asking.

I tried changing

```
String[] blue_members = new String[10], white_members = new String[10]; 
int[] blue_scores = new int[10], white_scores = new int[10];
```

to

```
String[] blue_members = new String[3], white_members = new String[3]; 
int[] blue_scores = new int[3], white_scores = new int[3];
```

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

// declaration of the class
public class Bowling7 

{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException 
    {
        // 1. connect to input file
        Scanner fin = new Scanner(new FileReader("bowling.txt"));

        // declare arrays below
        String Team, Member;
        int teamw, teamb, Score;
        String[] blue_members = new String[10], white_members = new String[10];
        int[] blue_scores = new int[10], white_scores = new int[10];

        // 2) initialize array accumulators to zero
        int teamblue = 0;
        int teamwhite = 0;

        // 3) display a descriptive message
        System.out.println(
                "This program reads the lines from the file bowling.txt to determine\n"
                        + "the winner of a bowling match.  The winning team, members and scores\n"
                        + "are displayed on the monitor.\n");

        // 4) test Scanner.eof() condition
        while (fin.hasNext()) 
        {
        // 5) attempt to input next line from file
         Member = fin.next();
         Team = fin.next();
         Score = fin.nextInt();


            // 6) test team color is blue
            if (Team.equals("Blue")) {


                blue_members[teamblue] = Member;
                blue_scores[teamblue] = Score;


                teamblue++;
            } else {
                white_members[teamwhite] = Member;
                white_scores[teamwhite] = Score;

                teamwhite++;
            }
        }

       if(sumArray(blue_scores) > sumArray(white_scores))
        {
            printArray("Blue", blue_members, blue_scores);

        } else {
            printArray("White", white_members, white_scores);
        }
            // 7) then store blue member and score
            // 8) increase blue array accumulator
            // 9) else store white member and score
            // 10) increase white array accumulator

        fin.close();

    }


    public static int sumArray(int[] Score) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < Score.length; i++)
            sum += Score[i];
        return sum;
    }

    public static void printArray(String Team, String[] Member, int[] Score) {
        System.out.println("Winning team:" + Team +"\n");
        System.out.println("Player Score" + "\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < Member.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf(Member[i] + ":" + Score[i] + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

bowling. txt consists of

```
Harry Blue 35
Tony White 43
Hilda Blue 92
Paul White 34
Tom White 20
```

OUTPUT

```
This program reads the lines from the file bowling.txt to determine
the winner of a bowling match.  The winning team, members and scores
are displayed on the monitor.

Winning team:Blue

Player Score

Fred:20
Harry:35
Hilda:92
null:0
null:0
null:0
null:0
null:0
null:0
null:0
```

(I should not be getting null:0)

Comment: Just add arraySize parameter on printArray and loop with arraySize instead of Members.length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array has a maximum capacity of 10, so its `length` is 10. However, it is only partially filled and the rest of the values are `null`s.

Because you loop through the array using the maximum capacity value, you get those `null`s on the output.

You need to add `length` parameter to your `printArray()` method to represent a number of elements which are really there, and use it instead of `Member.length`:

```
public static void printArray(String Team, String[] Member, int[] Score, int length) {
    System.out.println("Winning team:" + Team +"\n");
    System.out.println("Player Score" + "\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        System.out.printf(Member[i] + ":" + Score[i] + "\n");
    }
}
```

Then, call this method with an appropriate team length, e.g.:

```
printArray("Blue", blue_members, blue_scores, teamblue);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are printing the all the elements of the array by using Member.length then the array which has some values as valid while others are still unassigned and are null or 0 in the arrays Member and Score respectively.So Member.length will print your entire array irrespective of whether some elements have null or not.But when you pass the number of valid elements as 3 (or something else) then only first 3 elements of the array will be printed but **the other positions of the array are still assigned to null**.It is just that you are not printing it.
**He is asking to print your array till 3 rather than manipulating the size of the array.**

```
public static void printArray(String Team, String[] Member, int[] Score,int valid) {
        System.out.println("Winning team:" + Team +"\n");
        System.out.println("Player Score" + "\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < valid; i++) {
            System.out.printf(Member[i] + ":" + Score[i] + "\n");
        }
    }
```